# Select top and bottom rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I'm using SQL Server 2005 and I'm trying to achieve something like this:
I want to get the first x rows and the last x rows in the same select statement.

```
SELECT TOP(5) BOTTOM(5)
```

Of course `BOTTOM` does not exist, so I need another solution.  I believe there is an easy and elegant solution that I'm not getting.  Doing the select again with `GROUP BY DESC` is not an option.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Using a union is the only thing I can think of to accomplish this

```
select * from (select top(5) * from logins order by USERNAME ASC) a
union
select * from (select top(5) * from logins order by USERNAME DESC) b
```

Comment: There's also a way of using rownumber. And you should right top 2.

Comment: @hgulyan: TOP (x) is the preferred method - it works with UPDATE and DELETE, too, and also allows you to write `TOP (20%)` or `TOP (@limit)` and so on

Answer (score 10):

Check the link

[SQL SERVER – How to Retrieve TOP and BOTTOM Rows Together using T-SQL](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/03/02/sql-server-how-to-retrieve-top-and-bottom-rows-together-using-t-sql/)

Did you try to using rownumber?

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order BY columnName) as TopFive
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order BY columnName Desc) as BottomFive
   FROM Table
)
WHERE TopFive <=5 or BottomFive <=5
```

http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2009/02/select-top-n-and-bottom-n-rows-using.html

Comment: this code will not work.  `Top5` and `Bottom5` can't be referenced like this, you get `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Invalid column name 'TopFive'...`  If you put the `ROW_NUMBER...` in the WHERE you get `Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.`  You need to wrap the SELECT and FROM in a derived table and pull the WHERE to the outer query for this to work, like [@Paul did in the second method in his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927475/sql-server-select-top-and-bottom-rows/2927515#2927515).

Comment: Edited query. It was a big mistake.

Comment: This will run like a legless dog. Use UNION

Comment: @gbn I think it depends - in my case, comparing the execution plans for the 2 queries the UNION version ran almost 2 times slower - 65% vs 35% query costs relative to the batch

Answer (score 8):

I think you've two main options:

```
SELECT TOP 5 ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY ... ASC

UNION

SELECT TOP 5 ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY ... DESC
```

Or, if you know how many items there are in the table:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (
    SELECT ..., ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ... ASC) AS intRow
    FROM ...
) AS T
WHERE intRow BETWEEN 1 AND 5 OR intRow BETWEEN @Number - 5 AND @Number
```

Answer (score 3):

Is it an option for you to use a union?

E.g.

```
select top 5 ... order by {specify columns asc} 
union 
select top 5 ... order by {specify columns desc}
```

Comment: If you post code, *please* highlight the lines and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar!

Answer (score 2):

i guess you have to do it using subquery only

```
select * from table where id in ( 
           (SELECT id ORDER BY columnName LIMIT 5) OR 
           (SELECT id ORDER BY columnName DESC LIMIT 5) 
  )


select * from table where id in ( 
           (SELECT TOP(5) id ORDER BY columnName) OR 
           (SELECT TOP(5) id ORDER BY columnName DESC) 
  )
```

EDITED

```
select * from table where id in ( 
           (SELECT TOP 5 id ORDER BY columnName) OR 
           (SELECT TOP 5 id ORDER BY columnName DESC) 
  )
```

Comment: It's sql server, so instead of LIMIT, you need to use TOP

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Answer (score 2):

No real difference between this and the union that I'm aware of, but technically it is a single query.

```
select t.* 
from table t
where t.id in (select top 5 t2.id from table t2 order by MyColumn)
    or
    t.id in (select top 5 t2.id from table t2 order by MyColumn desc);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT x, rank() over (order by x asc) as rown
FROM table
) temp

where temp.rown = 1
or temp.rown = (select count(x) from table)
```

Comment: While it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s often more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand _why_ it addresses the problem. That can reduce the number of follow-up questions, and help new developers understand the underlying concepts. Would you mind updating your question with additional detail?

Answer (score 1):

Then you are out - doing the select again IS the only option, unless you want to pull in the complete result set and then throwing away everything in between.

ANY sql I cna think of is the same way - for the bottom you need to know first either how many items you have (materialize everything or use count(*)) or a reverse sort order.

Sorry if that does not suit you, but at the end.... reality does not care, and I do not see any other way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this recently for a very large stored procedure; if your query is quite large, and you want to minimize the amount of queries you could declare a @tempTable, insert into that @tempTable then query from that @tempTable,

```
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE ( columns.. )
INSERT INTO @tempTable
VALUES ( SELECT.. your query here ..)

SELECT TOP(5) columns FROM @tempTable ORDER BY column ASC -- returns first to last
SELECT TOP(5) columns FROM @tempTable ORDER BY column DESC -- returns last to first
```